# Dapper maps nullable Oracle database column, with null value, to default(T) instead of null

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net, dapper

I am using Dapper to wrap my calls to Oracle stored procedures. Many of the models that I map to have `int?` properties because they represent columns in the returned cursor that may be null.

There are two problems with my approach.

1. Dapper sees Oracle `Number`s as `decimal`s with `0` precision rather than `int`s. In almost every case, a `Number` in my database means `int` or `int?` rather than `decimal` or `decimal?`.
2. Dapper does not always "respect" the `Nullable`-ness of the target model property.

When the stored procedure returns a cursor of `TSomeType` with property `decimal? SomeColumn` and **at least one** of the returned rows has a value for `SomeColumn`, it will map all of the rows that have a `null` value for the returned column to `0` rather than `null` as would be my desire.

I tried in vein to write a custom `ITypeMap` that could be applied to ALL models to map `DbNull` to `null` rather than `default(T)` because the interface is not written in a way that favors **global** conversion of columns, but rather, conversion to specific types.

Any help is appreciated.